# Substituting all numbers with a value except a pattern with space with sed

Tags: sed

I have a txt file of this type:

```
360 181
363
-100
40
....
360 181
5
3
15
....
```

in particular this was extracted from a grib2 files, so the "360 181" line is essentially the header of the values, which tells me there 360*181 values (it is a gridded file). This was a grib2 files with many fields, hence, they are separated by many "360 181" lines, one for each variable.

I have to substitute ALL the values EXCEPT for the line "360 181" with a flag value, 9.9990003E+20 (i have to create a grib file with missing values).

```
360 181
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
....
360 181
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
....
```

I have been trying for a while now but I am stuck.

My tries have been:

```
 sed ’s/[^360 181]/[0-9]*/9.9990003E+20/‘ <in.txt >out.txt
 sed ’s/[^\<360 181\>]/[0-9]*/9.9990003E+20/‘ <in.txt >out.txt
```

but I have been unsuccessful.

There might be an answer out in SO, I have searched extensively, but there are many SED questions. If this is a replicate, apologies, please direct me to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **corrected version** of the OP's solution attempt:

```
sed '/^360 181$/! s/^.*$/9.9990003E+20/' <in.txt >out.txt
```

- `/^360 181$/!` is a *context address* that matches all lines that do not (`!`) *exactly* (`^...$`) contain literal `360 181`.

  - A context address is evaluated against each input line, and if it matches, the associated command is executed (to associate *multiple* commands, use `{ ...; ...; }`.
- `s/^.*$/9.9990003E+20` is therefore only applied to the non-`360 181` lines, where literal `9.9990003E+20` is substituted (`s`) for the entire line (`^.*$`; shorter alternative: just `.*`).

---

As for the **problems** with the OP's own attempts:

```
# BROKEN COMMANDS
sed 's/[^360 181]/[0-9]*/9.9990003E+20/' <in.txt >out.txt
sed 's/[^\<360 181\>]/[0-9]*/9.9990003E+20/' <in.txt >out.txt
```

- `[...]` is a *bracket expression* used for *character sets* (multiple characters (character classes/ranges), any one of which matches a *single* input char.), not for matching *strings*

  - As an aside: a `^` at the start of a bracket expression *negates* the following characters - a distinct use from `^` as the start-of-line anchor.
- The `s///` function takes only *2* arguments: the regular expression to match, and what to replace the matched string with.

Comment: I picked this as the answer because is very complete. thanks for the explanation about the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for line containing only digits with optional negative sign, and replaced it with the number required

```
$ cat in
360 181
363
-100
40
360 181
5
3
15
```

cmd

```
$ sed -re 's/^-?[0-9]+$/9.9990003E+20/g' < in
```

Outupt

```
360 181
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
360 181
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
9.9990003E+20
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just match all lines without spaces:

```
sed 's/^[^ ]\+$/9.9990003E+20/'
```